# SSRS Table of locations per item type

Tags: sql, list, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have a basic query which shows what the latest product to be put in each location (FVTank) is:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    T0.[DateTime],
    T0.[TankName],
    T1.[Item]
FROM
    t005_pci_data T0
    INNER JOIN t001_fvbatch T1 ON T1.[FVBatch] = T0.[FVBatch]
 WHERE
    T0.[TankName] = 'FV101'

UNION

SELECT TOP 1
    T0.[DateTime],
    T0.[TankName],
    T1.[Item]
FROM
    t005_pci_data T0
    INNER JOIN t001_fvbatch T1 ON T1.[FVBatch] = T0.[FVBatch]
WHERE
    T0.[TankName] = 'FV102'
                          [...etc...]

ORDER BY
    T0.[DateTime] DESC
```

Which gives a result like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is create a summary page on SSRS which would display all the locations which currently hold each item. Ideally it would look something like this:

[image]

There are 50 locations and 7 main items so I need it to have 8 headers (one additional one for "other".)

Is there a way to do this in SSRS? Or is there a better solution by doing it in SQL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional column to your dataset that calculates a row number for each `Item`, ordered by the `DateTime` field:

`row_number() over (partition by Item order by DateTime desc) as rn`

Judging by your source query in your question, this may be best included as a wrapping `select` around your final query:

```
select DateTime
      ,TankName
      ,Item
      ,row_number() over (partition by Item order by DateTime desc) as rn
from(
     <Your original query here>
    ) a
```

You can then use this as your row group, as without one you will not get the top aligned format you are after in each `Item x` column.  Remember to delete the `rn` column but keep the grouping:

[image: 1]

When you run this report you will get the following format (I didn't bother typing out all your data into my dataset query, hence the missing values):

[image: 2]

Comment: This doesn't include the "other" column but I think I may just prefer this presentation anyway. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you having an "other" column, what are you expecting to see in it and where does that data come from?

Comment: It was fixed easily enough by amending the query with a CASE WHEN. Thanks again.